# CS6 layer via copy is copying the opposite part

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I'm using the pen tool in Photoshop to select a part of my picture, but when I select the part and use magic wand tool to use **layer via copy**, it removes the selected part instead of copying it.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm confused by your question. Why are you using the magic wand tool if you already made a selection with the pen tool? Are you deselecting parts whithin the existing selection? Perhaps consider uploading an image/screenshot to demonstrate what you are trying to do.